# Как скопировать текст из консоли?

Tags: windows, консоль

Каким образом скопировать текст в буфер обмена из консоли в Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши в рабочую область консоли -> пометить -> ENTER -> вставить из буфера обмена данные туда куда вам нужно.

В некоторых консолях нужно нажать левой кнопкой мыши в верхнем правом углу(на иконку), там появится менюшка, дальше как описано выше.