# почему происходит ошибка при запуске команды "pip install": "Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>"?

Tags: python, flask, pip, установка

Пример команды: `pip install flask`

```py
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Users\user\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\user'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\user',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\Lib',
    'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311-32',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00001560 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

Пробовал импортировать несколько разных бибилиотек (keras, django, pygame, Pyqt5), но всё время вылетает следующая ошибка.

Windows 7, 32-битная версия. Python 12

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin , научите, пожалуйста, копировать текст в Power Shell/CMD

Comment: @Георгий выделяешь мышкой текст и жмешь ctrl + c

Comment: @RottenRat , не-а, не работает, пробовал уже

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472866/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, спасибо

Comment: А можете помимо ошибки еще код приложить?

Comment: @E1mir pip install keras, к примеру

Comment: А ну то есть эта ошибка выходит при попытке установить библиотеку, верно понял?

Comment: @E1mir, именно так

Comment: Тут есть несколько предложений, во первых убедитесь, что переменные окружения PYTHONHOME и PYTHONPATH не установлены, или если они установлены, они указывают на правильные директории Python. Помимо этого убедитесь, что на вашей системе нет других версий Python, которые могли бы конфликтовать с вашей текущей установкой. И последнее это попробуйте переустановить Python, полностью удалив все его версии. И лучше использовать 3.11 версию, так как 3.12 еще не вышла, а находится в предрелизной стадии, там тоже могут быть баги.

Comment: Почему вы пишете, что python  12, когда судя по логу используется 3.11 ? Возможно, установлено несколько питонов?

Comment: @Chorkov Я также думаю, 3.12 еще не вышла, она в предрелизной стадии

Comment: @Chorkov вы правы, действительно я устанавливал и Python 3.11, и 3.12. Сейчас снесу 3.12 и попробую ещё раз

Comment: @E1mir, удалил 3.12, теперь ни библиотеки не устанавливаются, ни запустить питон через консоль не получается :( ошибка та же (заменил на 3.11)

Comment: Что пишут команды `where python` и `where pip` ? Куда вы установили питон? есть ли путь к нему в переменной PATH?

Comment: Вообще-то на сайте python.org написано, что  Win 7 работает максимум Python 3.8.

Comment: @AlexTitov, да, я тож уже заметил ) Только зря активность развёл...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python 3.9 и более поздние версии не поддерживается на версиях Windows старше Widows 7.
Последняя стабильная версия в виде .exe-файла - Python 3.8.10. Версии 3.8.11 и более поздние доступны только в виде исходного кода.

Comment: Версии старше - это более новые. Не путать со старыми )

Answer (score 0):

может попробовать установить сам pip.

```
$ python.exe -m pip install pip
```